# Copy-Move Algorithm not working

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to implement the Copy-Cover (Copy-Move) image forgery detection [algorithm](https://benthamopen.com/contents/pdf/TOAIJ/TOAIJ-4-49.pdf) and I seem to be missing something. The matlab program runs without any errors but I get an output that includes almost the whole image.

Basic algorithm (as I understand it):

1. Create Nb x Nc matrix of PCA values where Nb = (sqrt(N)-*sqrt(b)+1)^2 and Nc is 27
2. Sort the matrix by row
3. Loop over sorted array and for |i-j| < Nn process the item (rows are next to each other)
4. Find the offset of the pixels being processed and discard the ones not near each other
5. Find the frequency of the coordinates found (count them)
6. Plot the highest number of points onto a new image.

Note: This only works on Grayscale images (of which I am using) unless you break out the RGB colors.

matlab Code:

```
%L = imread('images/lena3.jpg');
L = imread('images/Toronto2_F.png');
L=rgb2gray(L);
figure(1);
imshow(L);

b=256;  % block size used to look for duplicates
b1=sqrt(b); 
Nn = 5; % how many close rows to check
Nd = 15; %Threashold
Nc=26; % Truncate PCA at this length
Nt=26;

% calculate the total size of the image
n = numel(L);

b2 = sqrt(n)-sqrt(b)+1;
% calculate Nb
Nb= power((sqrt(n)-sqrt(b)+1),2);

% the matix of Nc plus the position
M=zeros(Nb,  Nc);
% temp index array
Mi = zeros(Nb, 2);
i=1;
disp('Starting PCA');
for r = 1:b2
   for c = 1:b2
       % Extract each block
      B = L(r:r+b1-1,c:c+b1-1);

      [pc, latent, explained] = pcacov(cov(double(B)));
      %[pc, latent, explained] = princomp(double(B), 'NumComponents', Nc);

      Z = pc(1:Nc);
      Mi(i,:) = [r c];
      M(i,:) = Z;      
      i = i+1;
   end
end

disp('Sorting M -> S');
%Sort M array in lexicographic order -> S
[S, index] = sortrows(M);
P= zeros(1,3);
disp('Finding Duplicates');
for i = 1:Nb
    iv = index(i);
    xi=mod(iv,b2) + 1;
    yi=ceil(iv/b2);
    j = i+1;    
    while j < Nb && abs(i - j) < Nn
        jv=index(j);
        xj=mod(jv,b2) + 1;
        yj=ceil(jv/b2);

        z=sqrt(power(xi-xj,2) + power(yi-yj,2));
        % only process those whose size is above Nd 

        if z > Nd

            idx = find(P(:,1)== xi & P(:,2)==yi, 1, 'last');
            if isempty(idx)==1
               P = [P; [xi, yi, 1]];                 
            else
               P(idx,3) = P(idx,3) + 1;
            end

            idx = find(P(:,1)== xi & P(:,2)==yi, 1, 'last');
            if isempty(idx)==1
               P = [P; [xj, yj, 1]];
            else
               P(idx,3) = P(idx,3) + 1;                  
            end            
        end                        
       j = j + 1;
    end
end

disp('Sorting findings');
rows = size(P,1);
% sort descending order
P = sortrows(P, -3);
% Mark the found blocks
disp('Creating Image');
idx = 1;
% Create a black image
RI = zeros(sqrt(n), sqrt(n));
while idx < rows && P(idx,3) > 5
    x = P(idx,1);
    y = P(idx,2);
    RI(x,y) = 1;
    idx = idx + 1;
end

figure(2);
imshow(RI);
```

matlab is not in my wheelhouse and I am sure the code above is not efficent, but honestly I am just trying to get it to work. Anybody have any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Note: a copy of the image can be found [here](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/) (I don't want to post since I dont know the copyright issues around the image), just copy paste a couple 81x81 size blocks of image around.

I have also included my own photo that can be used for testing.

[image: Original Image]
[image: Forged Image]
[image: Output of findings]

Comment: Can you provide the citation of this paper? Your previous link is broken.

Comment: I updated the link, however, for future reference the paper linked is 
"A Comparison Study on Copy-Cover Image Forgery Detection"
Frank Y. Shih* and Yuan Yuan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here seems to be on point 6 of the algorithm linked. It says:

> 6. Find out the pairs of coordinates with highest offset frequency

But you have:

> Find the frequency of the coordinates found (count them)

You're confusing the occurrences of pairs of values with the occurrences of offsets between pairs.
This is pretty easy to fix. Change the relevant section to:

```
    if z > Nd
        offset = [xi-xj yi-yj];
        P = [P;[xi yi xj yj xi-xj yi-yj]];
```

You then want to find which offsets occur most, that is which [xi-xj yi-yj] occurs most. Then, the values [xi yi xj yj] are those detected as being copied. You can use the matlab function mode to find the most frequently occuring element in an array, but you'll have to combine the 2 offset values into a single one. You can then mask the image to find the detected area:

```
rows = size(P,1);
P(:,6) = P(:,6) - min(P(:,6));
P(:,5) = P(:,5) - min(P(:,5));

maxValP = max(P(:,6)) + 1;
P(:,5) = maxValP .* P(:,5) + P(:,6);
mostfrequentval = mode(P(:,5));


disp('Creating Image');
idx = 2;
% Create a copy of the image and mask it

RI = L;
while idx < rows 
  x1 = P(idx,1);
  y1 = P(idx,2);
  x2 = P(idx,3);
  y2 = P(idx,4);

  if (P(idx,5) == mostfrequentval)
    RI(y1:y1,x1:x1) = 0;
    RI(y2:y2,x2:x2) = 0;

  end
  idx = idx + 1;
end
```

The result is

[image: image with areas copied blacked out]

If you want to go further:
You may want to clean up the stray pixels (i.e. those without neighbors). The region copied in the image doesn't appear entirely covered as the entire block corresponding to each value hasn't been masked out.

Comment: The check for sqrt(power(xi-xj,2)+power(yi-yj,2)) > Nd seems pointless, when I display the calculated value (z) its almost always > 15?

Comment: As I understand it, that section of code is ensuring that there is a sufficient offset between 2 blocks being compared. It's generally likely that two very nearby blocks (say an offset of 1 pixel in x and 0 pixel in y) will be similar, but that isn't indicative of copy-move. The number of occurences of such a situation is likely to depend on the image. It should be retained as a useful way to minimise false positives.

Comment: You have been a great help!  Thanks.